# How to loop through a table and read the first colum in every rowspan

Tags: jquery

How do I read each and every value of the first column using jquery?

I have the code  which is not working.

```
$("foo:eq(1) tr").each(function(){
                alert(  $(this).find('td:first[rowspan]').text());
            });

 <table id="foo" border="1px"> 
    <tr>                      
      <td rowspan='3' id="date"> Monday5 </td> 
      <td id="Name">Jim </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr>
       <td id="Name"> Remy </td>    
</tr>    
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/tes9E/4/

First, the jQuery [:eq selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) is zero-based.  Secondly, you need to put a `#` before selecting by ids, like so:

```
 $("#foo:eq(0) tr").each(function(){
   alert( $(this).find('td:first[rowspan]').text() );
 });
```

From jQuery documentation:

> **.eq**( index )
>
> **index** - An integer indicating the 0-based position of the element

Otherwise, everything looks great.  Hope this helps!

Comment: LOL @ghayes he wanted something else that i also came to know after a lot of time :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#foo:eq(0) tr").each(function(){ //--> Noo # and eq starts from 0
                alert(  $(this).find('td:first[rowspan]').text());
            });

 <table id="foo" border="1px"> 
    <tr>                      
      <td rowspan='3' id="date"> Monday5 </td> 
      <td id="Name">Jim </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr>
       <td id="Name"> Remy </td>    
</tr>    
</table>
```

Try this

**EDIT**

JS should be something like this

```
$("#foo:eq(0) td").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('rowspan')!== undefined)
    {
        alert($(this).text())
    }
});
```

[DEMo](http://jsfiddle.net/kritya/LFrNd/)

Comment: Thanks @Kritya, just wanted to ask, is there a way to find out if the row conatins a rowspan and if it contains it reads the 'td:first[rowspan]' else if the row does not contain a rowpan,it reads the first column of the row.

Comment: $("td:eq(0)").attr("rowspan") Will give u the value of rowspan

Comment: I have tried if($("td:eq(0)").attr("rowspan"))
                 alert(  $(this).find('td:first[rowspan]').text()); with the code you`ve given me, it is reading some blank values

Comment: One min let me send u a fiddle

Comment: As i said put an if on the code and set it to something like != "" or first use parseInt and then use != it is upto u. The thing u asked in ur question i have already answered if u want anything more please edit ur question

Comment: It is not reading the first column of the rowspan as it is reading Monday5 and Remy, which is not the solution to my question, it should be reading Monday5 only.  The question is: How to loop through a table and read the first colum in every rowspan

Comment: This time it`s reading Monday5, Remy, Jim.  I expect it to read Monday5 only, as I want to read the first column only

Comment: It gives only monday5 and i am 100% sure about it :/

Answer (score 0):

```
// A simple function that returns an array of cells within a specific column
$.fn.column = function(i) {
  return $("tr td:nth-child(" + i + ")", this);
};

// Using that function we can now select all the cells in the first column
var $col1 = $table.column(1);

// And then iterate over each one and do something
$col1.each(function() {
  return alert($(this).text());
});
```