# How to look for all the rows in a rowspan and set a class to all the rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">September</td>
        <td>Jim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dave</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>October</td>
        <td>Fred</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

using the code I am able to apply the class Red to the first row of the rowspan only, i.e, only Jim is being highlighed red and not Dave.  I also want Dave to have the class Red...Please note I want to apply the class per row and not per cell.

```
var fullRowNumCells=1;

$('#table tr').each(function(){
    if( $(this).find('td').length==fullRowNumCells){

        if($.trim($(this).find('td:first').html()!=''))
        {

                $(this).addClass("red"); 
         }            
   }            
});
```

Comment: No, only Dave is highlighted, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B4gUB/1/). You mean you want it the other way around?

Comment: Sorry... i didn't read well. Let me try. I will give you an answer in a few minutes (look Jamie answer just in case).

Comment: I want both Jim and Dave to be highlighted

Comment: Do you only want Jim and Dave highlighted, or do you want Jim, Dave and Fred highlighted?  Can you explain what you are trying to achieve - is it, highlight all the names in September row?

Comment: I want to highlight all the names in September

Comment: Please, see the update... Hope it's what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for tryingso hard @Jose, but this is not the answer.  I dont think your table resemble mine.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @learning Accept the answer if they work so the one who answered your question. And it encourages the person to reply to u again. Unlinke with me

Comment: it has not answered the question @kritya

Comment: @learning Did i mention this one ? Remember this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022198/how-to-loop-through-a-table-and-read-the-first-colum-in-every-rowspan/7022229#7022229

Comment: Your question is not clear. What should be highlighted, as a rule? Every row in which the first cell has a rowspan larger than 1? Rows on "leave"? There is nothing in your HTML that indicates which lines should be highlighted.

Comment: Every rows that "on leave" and may or may not have rowspan larger than1 .  see the image.

Comment: This is intriguing: after reading your question, every single comment and answer, I am still not sure what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Keep it simple.** For a table with n columns;

```
var n = 2;
var $rows = $('tr').addClass('red');

$rows.has(':nth-child(' + n + ')').removeClass('red');
$rows.has('[rowspan]').addClass('red');
```

Sometimes it's easier to think of what to **take away** then what to **add** http://jsfiddle.net/NV8uu/1/

Comment: Thanks martin, you answered it in such a simple way! It was indeed tricky.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

here is your answer. Is not the best code but it does what you ask:

```
$(function(){
var fullRowNumCells=1;

    $('#table tr').each(function(){
        if( $(this).find('td').length==fullRowNumCells ||
            $(this).find('td:not([rowspan])').length==fullRowNumCells ){
            if($.trim($(this).find('td:first').html()!=''))
            {
                $(this).find('td:not([rowspan])').addClass("red"); 
            }            
       }            
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bAFvT/

**Update 2: Less code. Hope it helps you**

```
$(function(){
    var fullRowNumCells=1;

    $('#table tr').each(function(){
        var hijos = $(this).children('td:not([rowspan])')
        if(hijos.length == fullRowNumCells)
        {
            hijos.addClass('red');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bAFvT/2/

**Update 3:** Now I hope this is what you want.

```
$(function(){
    $('#table tbody tr').each(function(){
        $(this).children('td[rowspan]').each(function(){
            $(this).parent().addClass('red').next().find('td:not([rowspan])').addClass('red');
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yn6AK/1/

Comment: Thanks @Jose.  I have tried to modify my table as shown in the edit part and it seems that th first column isn`t being highlighted.  I have tested it using your first answer.

Comment: Well, TH is not TD so... it won't be highlighted because in the code is not specified TH needs to be highlighted red.

Comment: I don`t want to highlight the header, but rather the column containing the date as well.  Date isn`t a TH  <td rowspan='1' > <label for= "Date" class="date">Monday, August 15, 2011</label>                        </td>

Comment: Did you solve it? Can you add an image with the result you want to understand you? :(

Comment: please see image and part of the answer ...jsfiddle.net/yn6AK

Comment: @Jose +1 for having to edit so many times :-P I've had to do the same before.

Comment: Here is the complete but simple sol. [http://jsfiddle.net/NV8uu/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/NV8uu/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're after. I'll put together a quick demo.

```
$("tr td:first-child").addClass('red');
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wTBe4/

**UPDATE 2**

Here's another example with your criteria that the cell contains some content:

```
$("tr td:first-child").addClass(function(){
    return $(this).text().length > 0 ? "red" : "";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wTBe4/1/

**UPDATE 3**

An example with elements containing a rowspan being excluded:

```
$("tr td:first-child:not([rowspan])").addClass(function(){
    return $(this).text().length > 0 ? "red" : "";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wTBe4/2/

Comment: So if the rowspan attribute exists, you don't want to add the class? Is that right? Because it's hard to tell from your question.

Comment: I don`t think you have understood the question: Please see here, @shadow has created a a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/B4gUB/1/